# Changing font size of chapter title without changing table of content font size

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, chapters

I am using document class report and I want to change the font size of chapter titles. I defined the following command to change title font size

```
\newcommand{\chaptersize}{\fontsize{25}{12}\selectfont}
```

It does change the font size of the title but it also change the font size of chapter title in the table of contents. Please suggest how to avoid change in the TOC.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In particular, there's no `\chaptersize` command in the `report` class, so you probably are loading some external packages and it's important to know which ones.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 2):

The chapter heading in report is defined by

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

So you can redefine that (between `\makeatletter` `\makeatother`) changing `\Huge` and `\huge` as required.