# Changing the chapter font size does effect the toc font size - why?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, fontsize

i'm new to latex and i'm wondering why the toc font size does change when i change the chapter font size.

For example. what i do is:

```
\chapter{\Large{This is my chapter}}
```

and this part of code does effect the font size of this chapter in my toc. But why? How can i change the chapter font size but not the font size of this chapter in my toc?

(btw: sorry for my bad english)

Hope someone can help. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you changing the font size of the chapter header in this way?

Comment: Because the argument of `\chapter` is also used for the ToC entry or the running head.

Comment: Also related: [Changing font size of chapter title without changing table of content font size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96029/changing-font-size-of-chapter-title-without-changing-table-of-content-font-size), [Format chapter's heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18213/format-chapters-heading)

Comment: @Mico
The related link doesn't fit to my problem because all i wanna do is just change the size of one specific chapter and not all of them. I want to change it because it has a large title and the style of it looks completly different compared to the other chapter titles. That's why i want to change the size of it. If i change the size to "Large" it fits perfect but the toc style will change also.

Comment: @mtzE - In that case, simply change `\chapter{\Large{This is my chapter}}` to `\chapter[This is my chapter]{\Large This is my chapter}`. By the way, do note that `\Large` is a "switch". It does not, repeat *not* take an argument.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use the `titlesec` package for this purpose. More instance, you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\Large\bfseries}{\LARGE\thechapter}{1ex}
  {\vspace{2ex}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? It is usually helpful to include some code that solves the OP's issue.

Comment: @TeXnician Done.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is that proceeding this way, `Large` is written to the .toc file, that `\tableofcontents` reads.

If you're using a standard class that with  `titlesec` and just write in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{title}
\titleformat*{\chapter}{\Large}
```

Comment: how do i change the font size of only one specific chapter title? I don't want to change all of them

Comment: You can use `\titleformat*` in the document body. To make it local, enclose  the command and the chapter within a `\begingroup` … `\endgroup`.

Comment: Thanks Bernard! But @Mico solved my problem in a comment above :)